# Deploying a Microsoft Access application with SQL Azure

Tags: database, ms-access, azure, azure-sql-database

How can I deploy Access applications to multiple companies, with linked tables to SQL Azure servers? 
I'm planning to deploy the Access programs with Microsoft Access runtime, and I'm assuming that I'll need to include the odbc drivers as well? Is there a way to automatically have Azure create a new server when a company signs into my website and downloads a program, and have the Access program link to it? And is there a way to get around the IP address settings in Azure as well? Because companies will be using the programs on multiple PCs. Or is it possible to utilise that and charge per PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you distribute the application pre-linked, then the user should not have to do anything to consume the data.

When using Access with SQL server you can in general use the standard windows built in SQL driver. However in the case of Azure you do need to download + install the native 11 drivers (so I recommend you use that driver during development and setup).

You can also have code include to re-link to the sql server, but as noted, if your application is “already” linked, then you really don’t have to do anything on application startup. Such re-linking would not be required every time the application starts, but only a “one time” re-link is required say if you’re going to change the database, or perhaps the user logon. How to re-link (DSN less) is outlined here:

http://www.accessmvp.com/DJSteele/DSNLessLinks.html

As noted, you really don’t need the above.

As for IP restrictions, in the Azure setup you can turn off such restrictions if you need a connection that will occur from any location, but that does open up a security hole. (when you first create the SQL database you will be prompted for firewall rules).

All of the above assumes you been developing that Access application with SQL server as the back end (you can even use the free edition of SQL express for development on your local machine).

Last but not least:
Because your connection is occurring OVER the internet, then you speed will be MANY times slower then using a local server. Read the following article to get a “grasp” of this speed difference:

http://www.kallal.ca//Wan/Wans.html

So MUCH additional work is required in Access to obtain good performance when your connection is OVER the internet as opposed to SQL server running on your local network.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing things then? At the moment we've been using microsoft access over a remote access to another PC, or just installing it in offices. I need a way to make it mobile, so that people can be out on jobs and still upload and view data.

Comment: A server setup with Remote Desktop likely is best. This setup works like remote access to a “pc” you use now, but the server creates as many fake “pc” desktops as there are users (so you don’t need a new actual PC for each user). This choice allows smartphone, iPads and really any computer/device with an internet connection to use your application. And this choice solves the slower internet connection problem also. So the system that allows many users is called “terminal services” – contact your IT support, they know what you want. No SQL  server is required nor changes to your application.